# Save unique "post_id" to locate div

Tags: php, jquery

This is the set up.

```
<?php echo '<button type="button" class="rh_show_button" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>
    Setting
<?php echo '</button>';?>
<?php echo '<div class="rh_content" style="display:none;" data-post_id="' . esc_attr( $post->id ) . '">' ;?>
    Content
<?php echo '</button>';?>

<script>
 jQuery(".rh_content[data-post_id='" + jQuery(this).data("post_id") + "']").click(function(){
    jQuery(".rh_show_button[data-post_id='" + jQuery(this).data("post_id") + "").show();
  });     
</script>
```

There is a button and there is div that is hidden.

Let say there are 10 buttons+contents. They each have unique post_id.
So, here is what I would like to do.

1. When the `button` is clicked, then the unique `post_id` is saved.
2. The saved `post_id` is used to located a div with that post_id, then show that particular div only.

Do I have the script correct?

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` will not be available when the you are trying to bind an element on load. Don't forget to put the following inside `$(document).ready();`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".rh_content").click(function(){
        post_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");
        if(post_id.length > 0)
           jQuery(".rh_show_button[data-post_id='" + jQuery(this).data("post_id") + "").show();
    });   
})
```

Reply to comment.

The value of `jQuery(this)` will only be available inside the function which is bound to the element. And `if(post_id.length > 0)` means that the clicked element with class `rh_content` has data-attribute `post_id` present in it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you tell me what "if(post_id.length > 0)" does.  And what you mean what `$(this)` will not be available? Thank you :)

Comment: @EmilyTurcato the value of `jQuery(this)` will only be available inside the function which is bound to the element. And `if(post_id.length > 0)` means that the clicked element with class `rh_content` has data-attribute `post_id` present in it.